# Start Workflow Automatically Help

Tags: workflow, tasks, task-list

I am very new to sharepoint but my employer wants to use it for build orders. I have created what appears to be a successful workflow and task list but am having issues linking them. I want to make it so that when my boss goes to our production order task lists and creates a new task, it automatically starts the workflow I've created, I also need certain steps of the workflow to be assigned to individuals based on who he assigns the task to in the task list. Is there a way to link these fields and trigger an automatic start of the workflow? I'm sorry for such basic questions but I've struggled on this for a few days now.

Comment: what fields you want to attach in the workflow?

Answer (score 1):

from SharePoint designer select your list and create new list workflow.

- [image]

Select the list name of yours and give the name for workflow and click ok.

- check the options in the workflow settings in the fig 2 as shown where you can check the option start workflow when the item is created.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you created a list workflow it should already be associated with the list.
To have a workflow fire on start or change you need to select those options from the workflow settings. You can access the Workflow Settings via the List ribbon. 
Or if you created the workflow in Designer you will need to edit the settings in designer.